# String includes another string or regex (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I need to check if given String includes a string or regex. If it does, it should return true, otherwise - false. How can I do it?

I have:

```
def method(string)
  if @text.match(/#{string}/)
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

But I'm not sure if it's a proper way.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a "write code for me" site. Instead, we help you fix problems with code you've written. Please show us what you tried, explain why it doesn't do what you want, and we'll gladly help you.

Comment: You can easily find your answer in the [ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html)

Answer (score 4):

Consider this:

```
@text = 'foobar'

def method1(string)
  if @text.match(/#{string}/)
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

That can be reduced to:

```
def method2(string_or_regex)
  if @text[string_or_regex]
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

String's [`[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method allows us to pass in a string or a pattern. If it's a string, the method uses it for a fixed-string/in-string search. If a pattern is passed in it returns the matching text.

However, Ruby is more friendly than this. We don't have to tell it to return a true or false value conditionally. In Ruby, a nil or `false` value is treated as false, and anything else is "truethy". We can convert a value to true/false using `!!`, which is double boolean "not":

```
true # => true
'foo' # => "foo"
false # => false
nil # => nil

!true # => false
!'foo' # => false
!false # => true
!nil # => true

!!true # => true
!!'foo' # => true
!!false # => false
!!nil # => false
```

Knowing that, and that String's `[]` returns a nil if not found, or the matching text if found:

```
'foo'['foo'] # => "foo"
'foo'['bar'] # => nil
```

we can reduce the original method to:

```
def method3(string_or_regex)
  !!@text[string_or_regex]
end
```

Here's what happens testing each of the methods above:

```
method1('foo') # => true
method1('baz') # => false

method2('foo') # => true
method2(/foo/) # => true
method2('baz') # => false
method2(/baz/) # => false

method3('foo') # => true
method3(/foo/) # => true
method3('baz') # => false
method3(/baz/) # => false
```

You have to be careful interpolating a regular expression object into another regular expression:

```
string = /foo/
/#{string/ # => /(?-mix:foo)/
```

The `(?-mix:` are the pattern flags being inserted inside another pattern, which can open your pattern to all sorts of weird behaviors and create extremely hard to find bugs. Instead, I strongly recommend using the `source` method if you're going to do that, which results in the original pattern being inserted:

```
/#{string.source}/ # => /foo/
```

Answer (score 0):

Code with single line:

```
!@text.match(/#{string}/).nil?
```